# In Android, how can I set the canvas size?

Tags: java, android, image, android-canvas

I have a frame that is 100% width and the height is also 100% of the  width. (If screen is 480 pixels wide, that means the width and height of the frame are 480 pixels wide.)

I'm writing an image editing appkication, and I need the frame to be the only place that a user can draw on. Is there a way I can resize and position the Canvas to the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically add a `SurfaceView` (or a `View`) of desired dimensions to your root layout and get that `SurfaceView's` `Canvas`.